# Bootstrap rowspan

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this Bootstrap design,two `rows`, their columns are `class="col-sm-2"` and `class="col-sm-10"`.

How can I make the rowspan like in the img below?

[image]

Comment: Is there a fixed height? If not, should both rows on the right remain the same height all the time?

Comment: They don't have fixed height for the left one @DrewKennedy ,and cols in the right are always going to contain a text and always with that height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see this. I have used bootstrap-4.

```css
/*this css is only for identifying row*/
.row > [class^="col-"]  {
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2);
 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          Level 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          Level 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is col a class of bootstrap? won't that approach break the 12-col-row design of bootstrap? @ankita

Comment: I have used bootstrap 4. because you mention bootstrap-4 tag.

Comment: I am still not familiar with the bootstrap-4 classes, but this approach worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes just easly use bootstrap classe

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color: red">
            hello
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10" style="background-color: red">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: black">
                    <p>a</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: yello">
                    <p>test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I came up with something like this...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 left"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-2">
    <div class="col-sm-12 rightTop"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 rightBottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;

  margin: 15px auto;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  //left is 15px to negate .row's negative mrgins
  left: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.rightTop, .rightBottom {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
}
.rightTop {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
.rightBottom {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

codepen example [here.](https://codepen.io/Piconey/pen/oGLEpz)

Comment: Your custom classes are completely unnecessary, and if you take them off you wont even need the `col-sm-push` class up there. This should work just fine as long as you place a second `row` inside the `col-sm-10`.

Answer (score -3):

```
<table width="300" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Merged</td>
        <td>Table First Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Second Row</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hope this will help you!

Comment: I can't use tables, I am using bootstrap classes